# Which is correct: "some quantities of the materials" or "some of the material's quantities"?

Tags: grammaticality

1. Some quantities of the materials listed below have been revised.
2. Some of the material's quantities listed below have been revised.

Which is correct: "some quantities of the materials" or "some of the material's quantities"?

Comment: Why are you spelling quantities and materials with capital letters?

Comment: @Micheal Perhaps it is a term https://www.accountingtools.com/articles/what-is-a-material-quantity-variance.html

Comment: In practice, ***quantity*** isn't usually "countable", and it's hard for me to imagine a context where either of your examples make sense. Are you sure you didn't mean ***qualities**?*

Answer (score 1):

They are interchangeable. In (1) "some" is used as a determiner. In (2) it is used as a pronoun, or some linguists call it a [fused determiner-head](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/511117/you-two-are-shallow-fused-head-np). There is no difference in meaning.